# Change width coverage of a background-image URL in CSS?

Tags: css, image, url, background, width

If I have a background image that is, let's say, 20px in width, and I want it to rather be 40px in width (but adjusting in photoshop would not work as I want it).

How can I change the width?

```
body {
    background-color:#5b7c8a;
    background-image:url('images/diagnol.png');
    background-repeat:repeat-y;
    margin:0;
}
```

It's diagonal lines as you can see from the image,

[screenshot http://img62.imageshack.us/img62/4263/testzjr.png](http://img62.imageshack.us/img62/4263/testzjr.png)

and the spacing is just as I want them. Editing the image may mess up the spacing. So I'm trying to get the background coverage area of the body to be a little bit more? Right now the image is 6px width. I want it to appear as 20px width, as if the image were in repeat-x-y in a 20px div? (so not stretching the image, just gaining more ground with the image)?

I hope this makes sense > <

Comment: http://img62.imageshack.us/img62/4263/testzjr.png

Comment: The link above is a sample - I would like the background image to "repeat" out 20px in width

Comment: What browsers do you need to support? This is possible in CSS3 but you lose a lot of browsers

Comment: Why would editing the image mess up the spacing?

Answer (score 0):

"adjusting in photoshop would not work as I want it"

CSS is not image editing software. In photoshop you just need to go to Image > Image Size and scale as you wish. Or take your time and learn to use the basics of Photoshop to get the effect you want. You just need to not be scared and experiment with each tool till you get what you want, as you can obviously undo the undesired effects.

The CSS way is possible but it's not meant for these kind of situations and will not be cross browser friendly. It's rarely used on typical sites so fortunately I'm not going to encourage it. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

I believe there's been misunderstandings with what the OP wants.

Incase i got it right, check out this example:

http://jsfiddle.net/vYxza/

Think of the `#text` as `body` and the `.this_div` as the element you need to create inside it.

Basically you create new element where you repeat the background in all directions but you just restrict the width of that element.

Another way of doing it:
http://jsfiddle.net/vYxza/1/ - **This is actually the way i would do it mostlikely.**

Note that again.. if you wanted to use it in body... think of `.this_div` as `html` and `#text` as `body`